# Chrome stopped recognizing openWin in the past couple of weeks

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

When I load my page that has not changed from the past two weeks when I last tested it, nothing happens. I am new to this and I am sure it must be simple and I am not seeing it. I have searched and not found anything specific to what I am experiencing.  I get the following errors from the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function quicktours.js:23selectState quicktours.js:23openWin quicktours.js:4(anonymous function)

Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function quicktours.js:23selectState quicktours.js:23openWin quicktours.js:4(anonymous function)
```

HTML:

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Quick Tours</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<script language="JavaScript" src="scripts/quicktours.js"></script>


  <div id="apDiv4">
    <DIV align="right"><FONT face="Arial" size="2">Selected State:&nbsp;
      <input type='hidden' id="stCd">
    <b><span id="currentState">None</span></b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <A href="javascript:changeState();">change state</A></FONT></DIV>
  </div>
  <div id="apDiv5">
    <p><a href="Javascript:openWin('image_mgr5','Imagemgr5QT','width=992,height=671,top=0,left=0,toolbar=0,location=0,directories=0,status=0,menuBar=0,scrollBars=0,resizable=0' )">Image Manager 5.0 </a>&nbsp;</p>
    <p><a href="Javascript:openWin('life_app','lifeQT','width=992,height=671,top=0,left=0,toolbar=0,location=0,directories=0,status=0,menuBar=0,scrollBars=0,resizable=0' )">Life Application</a>&nbsp;</p>
<p><a href="Javascript:openWin('lifeQuote','lifeQuoteQT','width=992,height=671,top=0,left=0,toolbar=0,location=0,directories=0,status=0,menuBar=0,scrollBars=0,resizable=0' )">Life - Application, Quote, and Purchase</a></font></p><p><a href="Javascript:openWin('life_annuity','lifeAnnQT','width=992,height=671,top=0,left=0,toolbar=0,location=0,directories=0,status=0,menuBar=0,scrollBars=0,resizable=0' )">Life Annuity</a></font></p>
    <p><a href="Javascript:openWin('life_scanning','LifeScanQT','width=992,height=671,top=0,left=0,toolbar=0,location=0,directories=0,status=0,menuBar=0,scrollBars=0,resizable=0' )">Life Scanning &amp; Imaging</a></font>&nbsp;</p>
    <p><a href="Javascript:openWin('PC_scanning','PCScanningQT','width=992,height=671,top=0,left=0,toolbar=0,location=0,directories=0,status=0,menuBar=0,scrollBars=0,resizable=0' )">P&amp;C Scanning &amp; Imaging</a>&nbsp;</p>
    <p><a href="Javascript:openWin('prod_mgr','ProdMgrQT','width=992,height=671,top=0,left=0,toolbar=0,location=0,directories=0,status=0,menuBar=0,scrollBars=0,resizable=0' )">Production Manager</a>&nbsp;</p>
    <p><a href="Javascript:openWin('RDP','RDPQT','width=992,height=671,top=0,left=0,toolbar=0,location=0,directories=0,status=0,menuBar=0,scrollBars=0,resizable=0' )">Rental Dwelling Policy</a>&nbsp;</p>
    <p><a href="Javascript:openWin('renters','Renters','width=992,height=671,top=0,left=0,toolbar=0,location=0,directories=0,status=0,menuBar=0,scrollBars=0,resizable=0' )">Renters Application</a></p>
  </div>
```

Java Script: This appears to be the culprit and I do not know why.

```
window.showModalDialog(url, args, "dialogHeight:150px; dialogWidth:350px; scroll: no; status: no; help: no");
```

```js
function openWin(appName, windowName, windowFeatures) {
    if (stCd.value == "") {
        selectState();
    }
    var qs = "?appName=" + appName + "&state=" + stCd.value;
    var url = "../launchQuickTour.asp" + qs;
    if (stCd.value !="") {
        var newWindow = window.open(url, windowName, windowFeatures);
        newWindow.focus();
    }
}

function selectState(curStCd) {
    var url = "selectstate.htm";
    var args = new Array();
    if (curStCd!=null)
        args[0] = curStCd;
    else
        args[0] = "";
    args[1]="";

    window.showModalDialog(url, args, "dialogHeight:150px; dialogWidth:350px; scroll: no; status: no; help: no");

    if (args[1] != "") {
        SetCookie("EAtrngStCd",args[0]);
        SetCookie("EAtrngStText",args[1]);
        currentState.innerText = args[1];
        stCd.value = args[0];

    }
}

function changeState() {
    selectState(stCd.value);
}       

function GetCookie (name, defaultVal) {
    var arg = name + "=";
    var alen = arg.length;
    var clen = document.cookie.length;
    var i=0;
    var j=0;

    while (i < clen) {
        j = i + alen;
        if (document.cookie.substring(i, j) == arg)
            return getCookieVal (j);
        i = document.cookie.indexOf(" ", i) + 1;
        if (i == 0) 
            break; 
    }   
    return defaultVal;
}

function SetCookie(name, value) {
    var expires = "Fri, 31-Dec-2010 00:00:00 GMT";
    var path = "/";
    var domain = "";
    var secure = "";
    document.cookie = name + "=" + escape (value) +
                    ((expires) ? "; expires=" + expires : "") +
//                          ((path) ? "; path=" + path : "") +
                    ((domain) ? "; domain=" + domain : "") +
                    ((secure) ? "; secure" : "");
```

Comment: what is SetCookie? Have a hard time believing this just randomly stopped working, considering it should have never worked.

Comment: @kevin B SetCookie allows a cookie to be set. And it is not relevant to my issue so sorry it is even included (at least I assume so). Please explain why it would not have worked period? It currently works in IE and it worked in Chrome 2 weeks ago when I last pulled it up.

Comment: The error you gave us suggests the error is on line 23 of `quicktours.js`. The closest relevant line to line 23 is the line that uses `SetCookie`. You need to figure out exactly what function call is throwing the error.

Comment: Your call stack when the error occurs is `(Anonymous function) > OpenWin > SelectState`, meaning the error is occurring within the `SelectState` function, on line 23 of quicktours.js. Either `SetCookie` is undefined, or `window.showModalDialog` is undefined. Neither of which are defined in the code you provided.

Comment: Then the issue is `window.showModalDialog` is undefined. Where did you define it?

Comment: @Kevin B I will be checking on this I have been pulled into another direction. Also I think that Chrome disabled this functionality and I am being told that my company changed our version and I was unaware. I still need to validate. Thank you for all your assistance.